# Updating column by calculation in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-functions, user-defined-aggregate

I am trying to add a new column in cassandra table to aid in some client side operations. The table is already there, and it has data in it. The primary key is a bigint.

The idea is to add a column on the table that would create domains of the primary key.

So the new column here is a int that must have the value of the <primary-key % 10>, which will give me 10 possible values for the new column, such as 10 pages based on the last digit of the primary key.
The primary key is named `idx` and the new column is called `idx_page`.

One idea was to add the new 'idx_page' column as CLUSTERING column, but this didnt seem to work, using an ALTER TABLE statement. IF this is supposed to work, then I am probably doing something wrong with my cql statement for altering the table.

Next thing I tried was to add new column, then add an index on that, because eventually client side will need to do SELECT based on the value of that column in order to fetch all rows that have a specific value on the new column. This worked fine.

Regardless of whether `idx_page` would be a clustering column or a plain column with index on it, there are still 2 issues to solve:

1. existing rows have a NULL "value" on the new column (which was expected)
2. I have to figure out the best way that when a new row is inserted, the new column will be assigned with a value that is calculated based on primary key, preferably not by changing all the client side code to do this manually.

I guess I could get around both issues by using cassandra FUNCTIONS and AGGREGATES ?

Ideally I would like to be able to call some function manually **once**, in order to update all existing rows, and assign a value to `idx_page`, which is always calculated by (idx % 10).

Then upon INSERT, I would like to have the same logic run *automatically* so that idx_page gets a value at the insertion phase.

I am not sure how to proceed with this, or even if I am on the right path with UDF/UDA.

Any comments or advice please.

Alex

Comment: I have tried to do an update operation such as:
`update table1 set idx_page = (idx %10); `
It failed and apparently it seems that currently only + and - are supported in this fashion, other operators including % (modulo) are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom function to accomplish this.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS moduluo (input bigint) 
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
   RETURNS int 
   LANGUAGE java AS '
     return input % 10;
     ';
```

Comment: Hi GAK  thank you. This solves the part that modulo is not directly supported inline. But  the 2 probles described in the original question are still unsolved.